# Getting redux's connect HOC's wrapped component type to use with React.RefObject without re-import

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, ref

I have a simple component that's wrapped with react-redux and I have a ref to that component with `forwardRef: true`, like so:

```
// Button.tsx

class Button extends React.Component {
  // ...
}

// ...

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, { forwardRef: true })(Button);
```

Now I have a parent component which renders the Button component

```
// ButtonParent.tsx

import Button from './Button';

class ButtonParent extends React.Component {
  buttonRef: React.RefObject<Button>;
  public constructor(props) {
    this.buttonRef = React.createRef()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Button ref={this.buttonRef}/>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Please note that this is a minimal simplified repro of the issue without unnecessary typings.

The issue is with the type of `buttonRef`. It classifies `Button` (which is the default export from `Button.tsx`) as a value, which is correct. It also suggests me to use `typeof`, which is incorrect.

The issue stems from the fact that `Button` is the HOC from redux's connect, but the ref's type is the actual `Button` class component.

It is possible to solve this by renaming and re-exporting the `Button` component, this way:

```
// Button.tsx

class _Button extends React.Component {
  // ...
}

// ...

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, { forwardRef: true })(_Button);
```

and then using `buttonRef: React.RefObject<_Button>`.

But I wonder if there's an easier / cleaner way to do it, maybe redux somehow exports the wrapped component's type and I just don't know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: a simpler extracting type:

```js
type WrappedComponentType<C extends { WrappedComponent: any }> = InstanceType<C['WrappedComponent']>;
```

I asked the question almost a year ago and today I encountered a similar problem and eventually found this thread again. In the last year I've got better at TypeScript so I've decide to re-tackle this and try to solve this, fortunately I found a solution!

You can infer the type by using redux's `ConnectedComponent` type with this helper:

```js
import React from "react";
import { ConnectedComponent } from "react-redux";

type WrappedComponentType<C> = C extends ConnectedComponent<any, infer T>
  ? T extends { ref?: React.LegacyRef<infer WrappedComponent> | undefined }
    ? WrappedComponent
    : never
  : never;
```

and then the type of `buttonRef`:

```js
this.buttonRef = React.createRef<WrappedComponentType<typeof Button>>();
```

If you're using functional components:

```js
let buttonRef = useRef<WrappedComponentType<typeof Button>>(null);
```